# Edit old question?

Tags: discussion

I have [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4989/what-could-cause-datepicker-to-render-blank-iframe). It is answered and solved, but looks a bit unformatted.

So I wonder if it is useful to edit both code-blocks to a more readable format? Any suggestions?

Because someone added a comment last time, [this question went up](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7590/how-to-debug-a-custom-timer-job-in-sharepoint-2010) and I fixed minor formats without reading date. So it leads me to think about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Definitely yes!**

A question is helpful not only to the person who asked it but also the people who are searching for that answer in the future. I always edit questions as I come across them to make them more readable... no matter how old.

Comment: Editing a question to improve formatting is my primary edit action nowadays on Ask Ubuntu (my main SE account where I have over 3.5k rep). Even ancient questions I edit occasionally to make formatting look better. This is so people don't have to figure out what is what (code vs. information vs. question, etc.) `Code styling is very` useful ;P